# Ruby won't start, problems with versions

Tags: ruby-on-rails

it is my first day with Ruby so maybe it is a very stOOpid thing to ask, but after 0.5 of a day I am giving up. I need to run an app written in Ruby 2.2.0. first I downloaded Ruby 2.3.0., but then got 2.2.0 as well and used a rvm --default use 2.2.0 command. 
Still in usr/local/lib/site_ruby there is only a 2.3.0. folder and when typing `sudo apt install ruby-bundler && bundler install` predictably I get an error:

> /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems.rb:270:in `find_spec_for_exe':
>   can't find gem bundler (>= 0.a) (Gem::GemNotFoundException)   from
>   /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems.rb:298:in`activate_bin_path'
>     from /usr/local/bin/bundler:22:in `'

I'd be very grateful for some enlightment
Ubuntu 16.04, app with Ruby 2.2.0, I have also Ruby 2.3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install bundler first. Try running
`gem install bundler`

Comment: Thanks galore! I'm confused by these bundlers and gems, I come from Python world :D The app still does not run, but it seems to be a bit closer :)

Comment: @fanny bundler is just a really convenient manager for gem dependencies. You can probably learn more from [it's github page](http://github.com/bundler/bundler)